# Customize openssl generate RSA key params

Tags: openssl, rsa, private-key

I want to generate a keypair with openssl, but I can't set parameters to generate my private/public key. 
I want pass an input parameter, for example a identifier (example mac address), to obtain an unique private/public key. For the same identifier I want the same private/public key.
How I can make this?
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Using OpenSSL's `RSA_generate_ex` may take some work. You likely need to provide an `ENGINE` that supplies a random number generator. Your RNG will supply the bits used by the key generation algorithm. Richard Levitte has a couple of tutorials at [Engine Building Lesson 1: A Minimum Useless Engine](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2015/10/08/engine-building-lesson-1-a-minimum-useless-engine/) and [Engine Building Lesson 2: An Example MD5 Engine](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2015/11/23/engine-building-lesson-2-an-example-md5-engine/).

Comment: A better option may be for you to create `p`, `q`, `n`, `e`, `d` and the CRT parameters. They are just `BIGNUM`'s, and you will completely control the form. Then, assign them to a `RSA*`. Standard warnings apply about messing with key generation this way ...

Answer (score 0):

RSA key pairs have to be generated randomly.

Making the generation deterministically - you no longer generate a key but derive the key from certain data (e.g. based on a MAC address). This reduces the security of the generated keys to zero - hence they are useless and you don't even have to start to generate them.

The central assumption the security of RSA bases on is that the private key is only known to the key owner. If you take a public information like the MAC address the following formula applies:

RSA key pair = your-derivation-algorithm( MAC address )

If you want to know the RSA private key (which is part of the key pair) you need the MAC address and the derivation-algorithm. The MAC is public and the derivation-algorithm will be public earlier or later.

Hence the RSA private key is public too, which makes it useless from a security perspective because everybody who knows the MAC address can generate it.

Keep in mind: Security bases on secret data in combination with a well-engineered algorithm. Whether the algorithm is public or not should not have any effect on the security. If it has an effect you have an insecure algorithm you can throw away.

Comment: Hi, can you explain me how generating the same keypair for the same input parameter I reduce the security of generated keys?